# System hangs on "Open document" right click context menu (Xubuntu)

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, thunar

Ok I recently installed Xubuntu 11.10 and I enjoy working with it.

However, one issue that really stresses me, is the following;

When I open **Thunar** anywere, and right click to open the Context menu, all goes well. However, when I hoover over the "Open Document" option, the system hangs for about 10 seconds. During that 10 seconds, nothing happens and nothing can be done.

I have googled quite a bit, but so far didn't find anything. I now know to add items to the Thunar menu, but that didn't solve anything.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Ok I have actually found the answer myself (almost accidentally). The key is your /home/templates folder; if there is a lot of stuff in there, Thunar will stall. Will post the answer as soon as I am allowed to :-)

Comment: DO NOT put the answer in the question put ni the answer area below!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the answer, after a extensive search on the internet and some helpful topics on Thunar. For the "Create document" right click context menu, Thunar looks in your /home/templates folder. So if you have this folder filled with random stuff (like I did, icons, other folders, backgrounds), Thunar will try to load all those items and hang/stall.

So the best solution, is to have your templates directory clean and only with a few necessary .odt, .doc or .txt extensions in it.